# Codeigniter: htaccess 301 redirect

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect

I have a fairly simple 301 redirect issue I'm trying to figure out. I have a page:

```
http://localhost/site/public_html/usa/fl/fort-lauderdale/page
```

That I would like to redirect to:

```
http://localhost/site/public_html/usa/fl/miami/page
```

In my .htaccess folder, I tried this:

```
Redirect /fort-lauderdale/page http://localhost/site/public_html/usa/fl/miami/page
```

And it didn't work. No errors or anything, I also tried restarting apache.

I also tried:

```
#RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} fl/fort-lauderdale/page
#RewriteRule ^http://localhost/site/public_html/usa/fl/miami/page$ [L,R=301]
```

Which DID redirect, however I got the "redirect too many times" error and the URL was duplicated like 30 times in my address bar.

Any thoughts?

Comment: you could add the following in the file that processes the request: `header('location:/site/public_html/usa/fl/miami/page'); exit;` Mind the `exit` because it needs to know it has to stop right there...

Comment: I've seen that suggestion before. Is that something I would add to my controller?

Comment: Yes, but if it the request always heads to the same controller so should add some extra checks.

Comment: Well, it did work, but we were hoping to do this using a 301 redirect!

Comment: This is the same as a 301/302/303 redirect. It's just not done by Apache... A redirect by php can be more flexible, because you can do the decision programmatically in stead of a more permanent, actually more hard-coded, way....

Comment: Ahh, I see. Thanks for the info, and we'll be using this in the future!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your .htaccess file add following:

```
Redirect 301 /site/public_html/usa/fl/fort-lauderdale/page /site/public_html/usa/fl/miami/page
```

Make sure your .htaccess file is the root (localhost folder). When you transfer it to server, move it to public_html (That would be the root on server)

Comment: Oh wow yeah moving my .htaccess file to the actual root solved the issue. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

In your `.htaccess` file add the following:

```
Redirect 301 /contact-us/ http://www.domainname.com/contact-us.html
```

**Make sure your .htaccess file is the root (Localhost Folder).**

When you transfer it to the server, move it to `public_html` (That would be the root on the server)